# Cannot post an answer containing two ampersand &

Tags: bug

On Stackoverflow I tried to post an answer containing two ampersand back to back ie:

```
&&
```

But I get this error (beware the image submit btn):

[image]

This is the question that the error occurred on:

[Dojo: Dealing with a priority list (ordered list) when using a Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113715/dojo-dealing-with-a-priority-list-ordered-list-when-using-a-store/23254984#23254984)

Comment: I've managed to edit your post to '&&', I've also [managed to post a replica of your answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qyLJ2.png) (containing '&&') on that question without problems. Normally, issues like this happen because of overzealous firewalls or proxy servers... are you behind any?

Comment: @Matt - Probably.  Thanks.  It still may be helpful to have a better error than 'an error occurred'.

Comment: ... but your firewall/ proxy is malforming your input. Having an error saying "The HTTP Header XYZ is missing" or "Missing cookie ABC" is just as meaningless to a user.

Comment: @Matt - Maybe on some stackexchanges (bikes, cooking, etc) but on the technical exchanges I know that I would find that helpful.

Comment: See, for instance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208912/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-question-with-mssql-query-text - crazy that it's && in this case, not even something slightly more sensical like the word "table". (Though only slightly. That's pretty messed up too.)

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: but your firewall *breaks the HTTP post*; the question page sends an AJAX request and that request is aborted; it never makes it to the server. That's indistinguishable from a network failure or a server meltdown. There is nothing to go on here. *There is no better error message*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the error message could be more or less what you posted.  Let me know 1) The request cannot reach the server.  2) This could be caused by no internet connection or a firewall/proxy.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: there are many other causes for the AJAX post to fail, and JS is not told about them. In the end all the JS knows is that an error occurred.